# Python function to get a column name based on element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a given DataFrame, that has unique column names but has duplicates in the single element'S values within the dataframe.
- My dataframe is About 10*2000

```
df = DataFrame({"R1": [1,2,3], "R2": [4,2,6], "R3": [7,8,2]})
```

Example #1:

> Input: 1
>   Output: "R1"

Example #2

> Input: 8
>   Output: "R3"

```
def get_column_name_test2(x):

    for k in list(df2.columns.values):
        if x in df2[k].values:
            return k
```

using this function i successfully retrieved the element's column. Yet when iterating it always gives me the first column that holds the x value rather than different ones (in this case it would Always return the "R1" column if the Input equals 2).

I've read that this could be also achieved by determining the position of the element, yet i didn't find a way to implement this function.

Comment: DataFrame isn't a python built-in, so there's no way that there's a built-in that does anything with a DataFrame

Comment: @wpercy Presumably OP has the line `from pandas import DataFrame` further up in the file

Comment: You will need to find the value within the DataFrame column/Series first. Maybe iterate through the columns by name and check to see if the value is in that column. Pandas docs - https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a build in function, however, the following should be reasonably fast:

```
input = your_input
# iterate over all your columns
for x in list(df.columns.values):
    # if the colums contains the desired value, print it/do whatever you want with it
    if input in df[x].values:
        print(x)
```

Or as a list comprehension, which follows the same logic:

```
input = your_input
result = [x for x in df.columns.values if input in df[x].values]
```

**Edit**

Regarding your given function

```
def get_column_name_test2(x, df):
    result = []
    for k in list(df.columns.values):
        if x in df[k].values:
            result.append(k)
    return result
```

This returns all possible columns in a list.

Comment: Heyy, so I've tried the Code, worked well so far. Yet if there is Elements in the dataframe that share the same value, it returns the wrong column. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: It should return a list of all columns that contain this value.

Comment: ah okay. is there a way to retrieve a unique column Name if there is duplicate values in the dataframe? MY Problem is, that if let's say R1 and R2 both contain the same value, it would Always return R1 as the related column because R1 is in the list before R2.

Comment: From your given code, I sadly cannot completely understand what you are trying to achieve. Besides, R1 is also a unique column name (and thus your requirement would be fulfilled). Since you have only the value as parameter, you should probably return all column names that have the value?